# Addition in field with finite int elements?

Tags: java, math, algebra

I need to write a function (in Java) which has the following input:

1. `int amountFieldElements`
2. `int summandOne`
3. `int summandTwo`

`amountFieldElement` describes the amount of int numbers in a range starting from 1 (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4 or just 1). `summandOne` is a int from this range, `summandTwo` can be any non-negative int.

The function has to add `summandTwo` to `summandOne`. If the result is bigger then `amountFieldElement`, it has to start over from 1.

I tried to simply use modulo: (summandOne + summandTwo) % amountFieldElements

But this is often wrong, e.g. `(3 + 1) % 4 = 0` but I'd need it to be `4`.

Example: If amountFieldElements = `4`:

`2 + 2 = 4` would stay as `4`

`3 + 2 = 5` would become `1`

`4 + 2 = 6` would become `2` etc

or for `amountFieldElements = 1`

`1 + 0 = 1` would stay as `1`

`1 + 1 = 2` would also be `1`

-> any result would be 1 here

Comment: I don't understand what is the purpose of `amountFieldElements`... Could you explain again?

Comment: Do you mean something like `(summandOne+summandTwo-1)%amountFieldElements + 1` ? It gets more tricky for negative numbers, but you have not specified what should be happening there.

Comment: If the sum is greater then amountFieldElements, it has to be set to a lower number, similar to mod operation. E.g. if amountFieldElement = 4:
2 + 2 = 4 would stay as 4
3 + 2 = 5 would become 1
4 + 2 = 6 would become 2
etc

Comment: Please add an example of specific inputs and the respective outputs.

Comment: Why would 4 + 2 = 6 become 2? I thought you said amountFieldElements starts over from 1?

Answer (score 1):

something like this will work:

```
int result = (summandOne + summandTwo) % amountFieldElements;
if (result == 0) result = amountFieldElements;
```

another method, shorter but harder to understand is:

```
int result = (summandOne + summandTwo - 1) % amountFieldElements + 1;
```

Comment: Heh, that's exactly like I do have it currently. I thought there has to be a better/more elegant way to solve this. But getting a confirmation that the way I thought of seems to be working is also great!